# send inputed value via javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I found a nice tutorial about create search bar [here:](http://benchung.com/full-width-responsive-search-box-using-css-tricks/) ...But I want to know how can I send inputed values to another page via get method?

for example if I typed 'google',It goes to http://example.com/google

I think JS can do it? can somebody guide me please

```
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="form-container">
            <!--<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" />-->
            <a class="search-submit-button" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
            <div id="searchtext">
                <input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="Search Something...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a class="search-submit-button" href="javascript:void(0)">
```

Leads to nowhere as you now

```
<a class="search-submit-button" href="#" 
onClick="location.href='http://www.example.com/'+ document.getElementById('s').value">
```

That does